# If you were to have asked

Tags: tense

I came across this English text below. I'm not sure what the bolded phrase exactly means. I think I've got the meaning of the whole text, but I would like to have some information about that tense. The author could have written also "If you had asked world leaders..".

> **If you were to have asked** world leaders from only a few hundred years ago which language they thought would become the most spoken language in the world at the dawn of the new millennium...

Comment: It's an [irrealis conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood#Conditional) about an event supposedly happened in the past.

Comment: An excellent question which must puzzle many learners; I have nominated it for the first ELL [question spotlight](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/818/32)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have understood the phrase perfectly: it is another way of saying "If you had asked..."

(My personal opinion is that it is a pointlessly pompous way of saying it; but I didn't get a vote.)

The base idiom is *BE to VERB*, where *BE* is the appropriate form of the verb *be* and *VERB* is the infinitive form of any verb. It means, approximately, "suppose", in both the senses in which that quirky word is used.

Thus, in the indicative (real) mode it means *be supposed or expected* to do whatever *VERB* names. For instance, *I **am to go** to London tomorrow* means "I am supposed to go" or "I am expected to go to London tomorrow".

In the *irrealis* mode, expressed with the past form, it takes the other meaning of *suppose*, "assume as a hypothesis". *If I were to go to London* (or, alternatively, *Were I to go to London*) means "Let us suppose that I go to London" or "If we assume that I go to London".

In your example, the author asks you to "suppose" not something which happened in the present, which would be expressed as "If you **were to ask** world leaders today", but something which happened in the past, a few hundred years ago. You have to 'backshift' the expression from present to past.

But you can't do that in the ordinary way, by using the ordinary past form of *BE*, *were*—because you've already used up that form in the present. The workaround in English for expressing a **past** *irrealis* is to employ the appropriate form of *HAVE* + the past participle of *VERB*: "If you **were *to have asked*** world leaders a few hundred years ago".

Notice that the same workaround is employed in the ordinary, non-pompous way of expressing the same thought: "If you **asked** world leaders today" is backshifted as "If you **had asked** world leaders a few hundred years ago".

This looks like a perfect construction, but it's not; it's the **past irrealis** construction.

Comment: What will be the ordinary way to say about going to London? "If I went to London tomorrow..." ?

Comment: @Graduate Depends. "If I went to London tomorrow I would miss my kid's birthday, so I'm not going." "If I go to London tomorrow I'll see Bob - do you have any messages for him?"